# How do I add a counter total to my user model based on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have users that have many points and points belongs to users.

Points can be any amount.

I want to be kind to my db by adding a total points cache to my user model so I can easily just do user.total_points

how do I go about implementing this?

EDIT: PS I am adding points for the first time so there's no need to go back and calculate points that users may have already earned...just need it going forward

Comment: Did not used it before, but there is a technique called 'counter_cache' built in with rails. But can't provide more than this keyword and a link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html (search for "counter_cache")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `counter_cache` technique if row in the `points` table constitutes one point. Otherwise you can implement it using a simple `after_save` filter.

```
class User
  # add a column called total_points and set the default to 0    
  has_many :points    
end


class Point

  # assuming `amount` column stores the points.    
  belongs_to :user

  after_create { |p| p.update_user_points(:create) }
  after_update { |p| p.update_user_points(:update) if p.amount_changed? }
  after_destroy{ |p| p.update_user_points(:destroy)}

  def update_user_points(type)
    delta = (type == :create) ? amount :
               (type == :update) ? (amount - amount_was) :
                 -amount
    User.update_counters(user, :total_points => delta) 
  end

end
```

Comment: Updated my answer to include the destroy scenario also.

Comment: why do you need to feed after_create, after_update, and after_destroy a block?

Comment: i'm kind of confused about what you're doing here. how does the code know what amount_was and amount are? do I need to set those?

Comment: My earlier code has an issue as `new_record?` returns `false` in `after_save` callbacks. We need to detect the context (i.e. create/update/delete) to calculate the delta. If you don't use the block form you will end up with three methods in your `Point` class.

Comment: The sample code assumes the `Point` model has a column called `amount` in the table. The `amount_was` is a Rails magic method which gives the amount value before change

Comment: I had to make one more change to the code. Refer to the ActiveRecord Dirty module documentation for more details: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty

Comment: I keep getting an error: point.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected '\n'

any idea what that means? line 17 is this:

    delta = (type == :create) ? amount :